# Error in dojo 1.9 custom widget extending dijit/form/DateTextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo

Developing a custom widget extending dijit/form/DateTextBox and get the following error:Error: Unable to resolve constructor for: 'GilCnPluginDojo.util.CustomDateTextBox'  Does anyone have a clue of what is going on?  Can't see anything wrong. This is my code:

```
require(["dojo/ready",
         "dojo/parser",
         "dijit/form/DateTextBox",
         "dojo/_base/declare",
         "dijit/registry"], 
        function(ready, parser, DateTextBox, declare, registry) {
         declare("GilCnPluginDojo.util.CustomDateTextBox", [DateTextBox], {
         postCreate: function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this.set('constraints', {
                 min: '01/01/1950',
                max: new Date(),
                datePattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy'
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: `return` is missing before `declare`. It should be `return declare("GilCnPluginDojo.util.CustomDateTextBox"...`.

Comment: You're writing this code in signle file ? like `CustomDateTextBox.js`

Comment: Thanks Himanshu and bRIMOs for you help.But the solution provided by barbsan helped me to sort this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign your declared type to variable to create new objects. See following snippet. (I've removed unnecesary modules and it misses some css file for dropdown but it's not important here.)

```js
require(["dijit/form/DateTextBox",
         "dojo/_base/declare"], 
        function( DateTextBox, declare) {
     var CustomDateTextBox = declare("GilCnPluginDojo.util.CustomDateTextBox", [DateTextBox], {
         postCreate: function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this.set('constraints', {
                 min: '01/01/1950',
                max: new Date(),
                datePattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy'
            });
        }
    });
    
    new CustomDateTextBox().placeAt('result');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.7/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.7/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id='result' class='claro'></div>
```

To use your custom modules in other modules you shoud use `define` instead of `require` and return your declared class.

```
 //CustomDateTextBox.js
 define(["dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/_base/declare"], 
 function( DateTextBox, declare) {
   return declare("GilCnPluginDojo.util.CustomDateTextBox", [DateTextBox], {
    //some code
  });
});

//MainModule.js
 require(["your/path/to/CustomDateTextBox"], 
 function( CustomDateTextBox) {
   var cdtb = new CustomDateTextBox();
});
```